# Unable to find BlazorWebAssembly JS files. This usually indicates a packaging error

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I received this error after changing Blazor WASM project from netstandart2.1 to netcoreapp3.1.I tried to clean, rebuild, remove all references and then delete bin and obj folders but still, I have this error.
This is the project file before:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\bg-BG.yml" />
    <None Remove="Resources\en-US.yml" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\BlazorShop.Common\BlazorShop.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\BlazorShop.Models\BlazorShop.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\logo.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Fills\" />
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Ingredients\" />
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Bases\" />
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Orders\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And this is after

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\bg-BG.yml" />
    <None Remove="Resources\en-US.yml" />
  </ItemGroup>

 

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Fills\" />
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Ingredients\" />
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Bases\" />
    <Folder Include="Pages\Admin\Orders\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```